# Unable to save file in ~/bin

Tags: macos, sudo

I have a script (which changes java version on user input) for development purposes and when I create a file using

`vi ~/bin/switch_java_to.sh` or `sudo vi ~/bin/switch_java_to.sh`

Then try and save it, I get the following error:

`"bin/switch_java_to.sh" E212: Can't open file for writing`

Output of ls -l ~/bin/switch_java_to.sh:

`ls: /Users/myUserName/bin/switch_java_to.sh: No such file or directory`

I have read that from update 10.11, apple increased security, but I don't know how to get around it, any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Increased security" does not apply to your home directory though. Please edit your question and add the output of `ls -l ~/bin/switch_java_to.sh`.

Comment: @Amadan Added to question

Comment: Do you have the `~/bin/` directory?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: Apparently not. OP, you have to have a directory before you can save anything into it. Use `mkdir` from shell (or `:mkdir` from vi) to create it.

Comment: Apologies, Windows user switched to Mac user recently, would've thought it would go to the OS's /bin/ directory and not the local directory specific to each user of the OS.

Comment: But of course I probably shouldn't of used ~/ with the /bin/ that was my problem hypothetically forgetting it's purpose.